# C# WebSocketSharp Event doesn't let me change WPF element content like Label text

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, websocket

Well I'm working on a C# WPF application which should work with websocket connection and send/recieve some packet as DATA...
I used WebSocketSharp.dll in project and everything works fine, but in websocket event such ws.OnMessage when I set WPF labels with some string, its doesn't change anything. But MessageBox show itself fine and in onOpen event the "Connected."-string will submit in Form.

```
namespace Kolbeh
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        WebSocket ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.34:9093");
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Content = "connecting...";

            ws.OnClose += (sender, e) = >
            {
                label1.Content = "closed.";
            };
            ws.OnError += (sender, e) = >
            {

            };
            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) = >
            {
                Messagebox.show("Ok");
                label1.Content = "Received a packet";
            };
            ws.OnOpen += (sender, e) = >
            {
                label1.Content = "Connected.";
            };
            ws.Connect();
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem? Because I need read some data from received message and put them in form.

Comment: You should really look at databinding these values to the ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSocket events are likely raised on non-UI thread, but WPF user interface can be updated only from the UI thread. You can use Dispatcher to achieve this. For example:

```
ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => label1.Content = "Received a packet"));
    };
```

**UPDATE.** You asked how you can pass the actual data. As far as I understand, the data is passed is the `e` argument. You can simply use this variable in your lambda:

```
ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
        {
            label1.Content = "Received a packet";
            DoSomethingWithData(e);
        }));
    };
```

Comment: Yeah , I See... thanks a lot. but how can i transfer data from Onmessage event into Invoke Function.